# Parsing pdf417 aamvaid in c#

Tags: c#, barcode, pdf417

I am attempting to read the back of a driver's license to decode the pdf417 barcode on the back. I tried using zxing.net with the following code:

```
var reader = new BarcodeReader();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>() { BarcodeFormat.PDF_417 };
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("bc.png");
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
```

The image is a test image I grabbed from the internet:

[pdf 417 test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIyzz.png)

I am able to parse out the PDF417 barcode but how do I get the actual driver's license data from this?

@

ANSI 6360050101DL00300203DLDAQ3265188
DAALOTT,ERIC,B,
DAG763 TEST STREET
DAINEW YORK CITY
DAJSC
DAK10005
DARD
DAS
DAT
DAU601
DAW170
DAYBRO
DAZBRO
DBA20241004
DBB19911004
DBC1
DBD20140101
DBG2
DBH1

Answer (score 2):

Most of the 50 U.S. states follow the AAMVA DL/ID standards https://www.aamva.org/topics/driver-license-and-identification-standards?#?wst=4a3b89462cc2cff2cbe0c7accde57421/. Go to the website and scroll down to **AAMVA DL/ID Card Design Standard (2020)** and download the PDF. Annex D explains all of the data elements inside the barcode contents. According to this document, the driver's license starts after its element `DAQ`. So in your example, the driver's license is `3265188` which appears after `DAQ` and before the next element, `DAA`, starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEADTOOLS Forms SDK technology in your application.
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/forms/recognition-processing
You can leverage the BarcodeEngine and AAMVAID classes, which will allow you to recognize the PDF417 AAMVA barcode and extract the encoded information. Do note that I am an employee of this toolkit.

**DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit.**

Here is some sample code:

```
using (RasterCodecs _codecs = new RasterCodecs())
using (RasterImage _image = _codecs.Load(@"C:\LEADTOOLS21\Resources\Images\license_sample_rear_aamva.png"))
{
    // Create the BarcodeEngine
    BarcodeEngine _bcEngine = new BarcodeEngine();
    BarcodeData _data = _bcEngine.Reader.ReadBarcode(_image, LeadRect.Empty, BarcodeSymbology.PDF417);
    if (_data.Value != null && _data.Symbology == BarcodeSymbology.PDF417)
    {
        AAMVAID _id = BarcodeData.ParseAAMVAData(_data.GetData(), false);
        if (_id != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AAMVA PDF417 Barcode Found!\n" + 
                  "==============================================="); 
            Console.WriteLine($"Issuer Identification Number: {_id.IssuerIdentificationNumber}\n" + 
                  $"First Name: {_id.FirstName.Value}\n" + 
                  $"Last Name: {_id.LastName.Value}\n" + 
                  $"Over 21? {_id.Over21}\n");
            // Note: There are many more properties in the AAMVAID class to gather data. 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Does not meet AAMVA specifications");   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PDF417 Barcode Not Found!");
    }
}
```

I tried the barcode in your image and this is what I received.

[AAMVA Extraction Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae0cP.jpg)